# What's the equivalent of EasyMock.aryEq function in OCMOCK

Tags: ios, ocmock

I have a problem when i try to implement some tests in IOS using OCMOCK; Indeed, i need the equivalent of easy mock ary eq to expect  byte array argument is equal to the given array.
here's an example:

```
invoked:  openConnectionWithJavaLangByteArray:[0xffffffa0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10]
expected: openConnectionWithJavaLangByteArray:[0xffffffa0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x10, 0x10, 0x10]
```

The buffers argument are same but we need , like when implementing in java to use ary eq to compare the equality of these two buffers.
any help?
thanks.

Comment: What is the type of these arrays? char[]?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[OCMArg checkWithBlock:]`
Example:

```
[[yourMockObject expect] someMethodWithParameter:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(id param)
                                                  {
                                                      // assertions with param here.
                                                      // return BOOL indicating if the expectation passed or not.
                                                  }]];
[yourMockObject verify];
```

Comment: If user's array is a raw C type I don't think this would work, but it is a great approach generally!